# Convert RSA openSSH key/putty key to gpg key

Tags: windows, ssh, gnupg

## Scenario

Two work sites, site 1 and site 2. Two Linux servers, server A and server B. Server A is reachable from both sites, while server B is reachable from site 1 only. Two Windows workstations, one at site 1, the other at site 2.

I'm on Windows at site 1, using PuTTY to connect to server A that's set to ssh publickey authentication only.

I use gpg-agent with the `enable-putty-support` setting activated instead of pageant to use a smartcard for git authentication at `$popular_git_site`.

Most of the time at site 1, I need to remotely connect to server B using NoMachine's NX Client v3.5.x. From there, I need to be able to ssh into server A using publickey authentication as well. Since server B is running NX Server v3.5.x, agent-forwarding does not work using NX Client. Thus, with the smartcard unavailable, I have to make sure I have a private key available on server B.

Therefore, I created a password-protected RSA ssh key pair with on server B using

```
 ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

The password is `verylongandcomplicatedpassword`. Thus, I don't want to type it a lot.

I appended the public key `.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to `.ssh/authorized_keys` on server A as well as on server B. Using ssh from server B to server A works now. Vice-versa also works now.

## Problem

On Windows at site 1 I have a PuTTY connection set-up to server B using agent-forwarding for my smartcard in order to be able to use git on server B and authenticate with my smartcard.

I want the same thing for server A, because server B is unreachable from site 2, where I also work sometimes. `gpg-agent` is started as a Startup item using `gpg-connect-agent /bye` and is running on Windows.

Thus, I `scp`'d the private key `.ssh/id_rsa` from server B onto my Windows machine. I successfully opened it with PuTTYgen and saved it in PuTTY format to `C:\Users\name\ssh\id_rsa.ppk`.

I created a new PuTTY connection to server A, connection type `SSH`.

```
Connection --> SSH --> Auth -->
    [Check]   Attempt Authentication using Pageant
    [Uncheck] Attempt "keyboard-interactive" auth
    [Check]   Allow agent forwarding
    Private Key File for Authentication: C:\Users\name\ssh\id_rsa.ppk
```

This sort of works. However, PuTTY itself -- not `gpg-agent` -- prompts me for the password `verylongandcomplicatedpassword` -- **every time**! Agent forwarding also doesn't work insomuch as that I'm unable to go from server A to server B without retyping my password after successful login from PuTTY.

I think PuTTY is unable to add the key to `gpg-agent` or communicate with it properly despite `enable-putty-support` being activated in the `gpg-agent` configuration and `gpg-agent` working like a champ for git and agent-forwaring working for git on server B at site 1.

## What I tried

Thinking I'm extremely clever, I began to look into how to convert my `.ssh/id_rsa` to a format I can use in gpg2 for `gpg-agent`. This Google search yielded mostly bullshit results.

The best of which -- because it actually sort of mentions a way to convert the key -- is [over here](http://www.sysmic.org/dotclear/index.php?post/2010/03/24/Convert-keys-betweens-GnuPG%2C-OpenSsh-and-OpenSSL).

> OpenSSH to GnuPG S/MIME
>
> First we need to create a certificate (self-signed) for our ssh key:
>
> ```
> openssl req -new -x509 -key ~/.ssh/id_rsa -out ssh-cert.pem
> ```
>
> We can now import it in GnuPG
>
> ```
> openssl pkcs12 -export -in ssh-certs.pem -inkey ~/.ssh/id_rsa -out ssh-key.p12
> gpgsm --import ssh-key.p12
> ```
>
> Notice you cannot import/export DSA ssh keys to/from GnuPG

Said and done. Notice obvious typo in second command (ssh-cert**s**.pem vs ssh-cert.pem). I did all `openssl` commands on server B, then copied the `ssh-key.p12` file over to Windows and imported it into gpg. I can see the key as X.509 in Kleopatra, a graphical frontend for gpg on Windows.

However, despite this, nothing changed and nothing seems to be working. I tried with the original PuTTY settings above. The behavior is unchanged.

Leaving the `Private Key File for Authentication` field empty, I get the usual message:

> PuTTY Fatal Error
>   Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)

I'm ignorant as to why this isn't working. Is GnuPG S/MIME or X.509 not what I need? I tried converting the `.ssh/id_rsa.pub` as well, thinking it might be a public key issue, but `openssl` complains that it only wants to convert private keys.

## What I don't need

Answers suggesting

- I'm stupid for wanting this
- nobody would never ever need to want to do this
- if I don't like how ssh/gpg/PuTTY works, I can code my own
- man gpg, man ssh, man ssh_config

Comment: Keys imported using `gpgsm` still are X.509 keys and stored in a different keyring than OpenPGP keys. Importing an X.509 key in GnuPG using `gpgsm` does _not_ make it an OpenPGP key.

Comment: @JensErat I'm aware of this. I wasn't aware whether X.509 precludes me from using the cert for authentication. Apparently, it does.